# Error in the installation of tesseract ( pycharm python)

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, tesseract

I have installed open-cv, jupyter ... But i have problems with tesseract. I have installed tesseract application but i can't install this on pycharm. Someone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need to install the executable file. The link of downloading executable file on windows: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. If you have already installed the executable file of tesseract then you can install it from the terminal of pycharm via pip.

> pip install pytesseract

When running the program you need to specify the executable file location where you installed it for tesseract_cmd variable. For example:

> `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I solved it by changing the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion. I solved it by changing the environment variables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).